# How to load to container MassTransit EndPoint in AbstractFacility

Tags: castle-windsor, masstransit

I have a PersistenceFacility class . 
This class inhereted "AbstractFacility" as "Castle.MicroKernel.Facilities".
I wonder load and install into container: IWindsorContainer.

```
public class PersistenceFacility: AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {

        ServiceIoC.Container.Register(Component.For<IBusControl>().LifeStyle.Singleton.UsingFactoryMethod(k =>
        {
            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                config.Host(new Uri("blabla"), host =>
                {
                    host.Username("guest");
                    host.Password("guest");
                });

                config.ReceiveEndpoint("", endpoint =>
                {
                    endpoint.EnableMessageScope();
                    // Above method works but it is deprecated, instead below method should be used to get Consumer from container.
                    //endPoint.Consumer<YourConsumer>(container.Kernel);
                });
            });

            return busControl;

        }).LifeStyle.Singleton.Named("XXXMassTransitRMQ"));
```

}

// installer class

```
public class PersistenceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container?.AddFacility<PersistenceFacility>();
    }
}
```

//UOW Class

```
 public class UnitOfWork
{
     internal static IBusControl MassTransitRmqControl => ServiceIoC.Container?.Resolve<IBusControl>("XXXMassTransitRMQ");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I would consider moving to use the new container support for Windsor, as outlined in the [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/castlewindsor.html).

You can see how MassTransit registers components with Windsor by looking at the [configuration](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Containers/MassTransit.WindsorIntegration/Registration/WindsorContainerRegistrationConfigurator.cs#L37).

I'm not sure an abstract facility is the way to go, given the approach taken by the links referenced above.